Restrict access to specific CodeBuild projects
We're using AWS CodeBuild to run a process to deploy code changes. This is run manually when a user wants to deploy the changes. So far we've set this up for deploying to dev servers. We now want to set up a process to deploy to production.
I want to create a second build project, but I don't want every user that can access codebuiild to be able to run it. I can't see anywhere how to restrict specific users from accessing a specific project.
